# how to create multiple logical tables in single levelDB instance?

Tags: key-value-store, leveldb

I am working on a Distributed key-value system (or data-store), which uses [levelDB](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) as its embedded database library in the back-end.

I want one node/machine to host multiple tables (for the purpose of replication and load-balancing). I understand levelDB has no notion of tables, so I cannot logically partition my data in form of tables (hence cannot use these tables as my basic unit of distribution).

**My question is:** is there a provision of having multiple 'logical tables' in single instance of levelDB ?

From what I know, I can have multiple instances of levelDB running on my node each handling one table. But I do not want to do that, since in this case there will be serious contention (at disk I believe) when these multiple DB instances are accessed simultaneously. While having multiple logical tables in single instance of DB can give me advantages of levelDB optimizations for minimizing disk accesses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have multiple "logical tables" in LevelDB, then you have to partition your key space or add a prefix to the keys. For each table create a different prefix, eg:

```
0x0001 is for table 1
0x0002 is for table 2
0x0003 is for table 3
and so on...
```

So a key would consist of the table prefix and the key itself: [0x0001,0xFF11] would address key 0xFF11 in table 1. You can then use a single LevelDB instance and have multiple "key spaces" which would correspond to "tables".

Comment: Yes.. looks like this is the only way. I thought of using one filesystem directory for each tablet but apparently if you open multiple directories (using Open(options,<dir-path>, &db)) only last directory is used for data-storage.

Comment: And anyways open method does not give unique DB handler for each directory (or open operation).

Comment: I don't know how you managed to open multiple directories with a single LevelDB instance... so I don't know what you mean that "only the last directory is used for data-storage." If you need multiple directories, then you need to use multiple LevelDB instances.

Comment: since open() was not throwing any error for multiple directories.. I 'assumed' all the directories passed to open would be stored to save the data 
Thanks for replying.. I eventually decided to use multiple levelDB instance .. which made things lot more simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is partitioning the key space using a key prefix as suggested by Lirik. Though opening multiple databases is possible, I would not recommend it for your use case, since the databases will not share any buffers and caches. Working with multiple open databases may negatively impact performance, and it will make optimizing resource use (mostly memory) a lot harder.

Comment: @Wouter.. Yes I completely agree with your point. Not only buffer and caches would not be so effective,also the disk may go crazy too handling multiple instances of DB. I am using multiple instances for my system for now, but I will use the key-prefix method before I put it in production. Thanks.

Comment: Fwiw, my Plyvel project has a really nice API for this. See https://plyvel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#prefixed-databases for more information. In case you're not using Python you may still be interested in how it works (and you can probably copy its implementation).